# function to make int into string to add to map python

Tags: python, random, dictionary

I have just started learning python yesterday. The task is to randomly generate 5 colours from

```
c=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "white", "black"]
```

So I use
    random.choice(c)

To create a list of 50 I would of thought to create a function then add it to map() using a function to add a random colour and the iterating through range(1,51)

To essentially change the number 1 2 3 4 etc. to a randomly chosen colour.

I don't know how I could change the number into a random.choice(c) - So what function I could use for the map i.e.

```
print map('function', range(1,51))
```

I thought about using lambda like

```
>>> sums = lambda x:(x-x)+(random.choice(c))
>>> print map(sums,range(1,51))
```

but I got,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    print map(sums,range(1,51))
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <lambda>
    sums = lambda x:(x-x)+(random.choice(c))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

But it obv didnt work because im + an int to string

I am trying to look through documentation for something but having no luck

Any tips on what I can do

Comment: Could you provide some example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to provide a function to `map` that discards the argument given to it and generates a totally independent value. It's permissible to have a lambda with an argument that is never used in the expression body. You don't have to try to trick the interpreter with (x-x).

```
sums = lambda x: random.choice(c)
print map(sums, range(1,51))
```

Comment: In the assignment spec it does state to use map although list comprehension looks easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can get 50 colors like so:

```
>>> c = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "white", "black"]
>>> for _ in range(50):
...     random.choice(c)
...     
... 
'blue'
'red'
'yellow'
...
```

To generate a list of 50 colors, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> colors = [random.choice(c) for _ in range(50)]
>>> colors
['green', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'orange', 'black', 'black', 'purple', 'red',
 'black', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'purple', 'orange', 'white', 'red', 'gree
n', 'black', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'orange', 'blue', 'white', 'blue', 'oran
ge', 'black', 'orange', 'green', 'black', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'blue', 'gr
een', 'green', 'white', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'p
urple', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 'black', 'red']
```

You can use `map` like this as well:

```
>>> map(lambda _: random.choice(c), range(50))
['purple', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'purple', 'red', 'blue'
, 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'white', 'blue', 'orange', 'whit
e', 'yellow', 'black', 'green', 'white', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'red',
 'black', 'purple', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 're
d', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'red', 'white', 'orang
e', 'green', 'purple', 'white', 'green', 'green']
```

Or you can even omit the `_` in the `lambda`:

```
>>> map(lambda: random.choice(c), range(50))
```

The `_` in all versions indicate a variable that is not used. It could be anything, like `i` or `number`. For instance in your case, you never really want to use the number which the `range` function produces. It's a convention.

Comment: `_` is just the variable name for the cursor in the iterator.  Using `_` is convention for a variable that is not actually used, but is syntactically required.

Comment: I've edited a response to the comment in the answer.

Comment: +1 list comprehension looks easier but assignment spec is to use map()

Comment: @dhali added a `map` there just for the record.